# How to Pass Data From Pop-Over Subview to View Controller with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to pass the text data from my `UITextField` (taskNameField) subview that's apart of my `taskCreator` subview. Not sure how to get my hands on this data outside of the subview so that I can add it to my task array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

var userTasks: [Task] = []

class PlannerViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

static let viewHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
static let viewWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 110, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 30, height: 60)

    let myCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    myCollectionView.dataSource = self
    myCollectionView.delegate = self
    myCollectionView.register(TaskCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
    myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)

    let addButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.width - 70, y: view.frame.height - 120, width: 50, height: 50))
    addButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    addButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlusIcon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addTask), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(addButton)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return cell
}

@IBAction func addTask(sender: UIButton) {
    view.addSubview(taskCreator)
}

@IBAction func saveTask(sender: UIButton) {
    taskCreator.removeFromSuperview()
}

let taskCreator: UIView = {
    let object = UIView()
    object.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: viewWidth - 20, height: viewHeight - 350)
    object.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    object.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let taskNameField: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: object.frame.width - 40, height: 30)
        field.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        field.placeholder = "New Task"
        field.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment(rawValue: 3)!
        field.becomeFirstResponder()
        return field
    }()

    let doneButton: UIButton = {
        let done = UIButton()
        done.frame = CGRect(x: viewWidth / 2 - 55, y: 200, width: 90, height: 30)
        done.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        done.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        done.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveTask), for: .touchUpInside)
        return done
    }()

    object.addSubview(taskNameField)
    object.addSubview(doneButton)

    return object
}()

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the *value* of a `UITextField` it is as simple as this.

```
var textFieldValue = taskNameField.text
```

However if you need it immediately after the user has entered something into the text field, then you need to use delegate methods available in the `UITextFieldDelegate` which your `UIViewController` has to conform to.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    var textFieldValue = textField.text
    // Do something with the value like adding it to a Task object
}
```

If you need to access your text field outside your view, then you need to declare it outside. Also declare them as `lazy` so that they are created only when needed.

```
lazy var doneButton: UIButton = {
    let done = UIButton()
    done.frame = CGRect(x: viewWidth / 2 - 55, y: 200, width: 90, height: 30)
    done.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    done.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    done.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveTask), for: .touchUpInside)
    return done
}()

lazy var taskNameField: UITextField = {
    let field = UITextField()
    field.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: object.frame.width - 40, height: 30)
    field.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    field.placeholder = "New Task"
    field.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment(rawValue: 3)!
    field.becomeFirstResponder()
    return field
}()

lazy var taskCreator: UIView = {
    let object = UIView()
    object.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: viewWidth - 20, height: viewHeight - 350)
    object.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    object.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    object.addSubview(taskNameField)
    object.addSubview(doneButton)

    return object
}()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The thing that's catching me up is that I'm not sure how to access that UITextField text data outside of the subview. Any tips on that?

Comment: @CarterFoughty i see your problem. Just move your text field outside of the view declaration closure. It doesn't need to be created inside it to be added to the view. Declare it outside and you'll still be able to access it inside to add subview.

Comment: Apologies - didn't see your response! Unfortunately, when I did that, I get the error saying "Instance member 'taskNameField' cannot be used on type 'PlannerViewController'", when I try to add it as a subview. Any tips?

Comment: You are trying to add it as `object.addSubview(taskNameTextField)` right which is a lazy var?

Comment: Ignore my last comment - I was able to fix that. Thank you so much! You've been massively helpful!